# How to indent sub-heading along with content in GitHub Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to create my `README` file, and I wish that my sub-heading gets indented.

In particular, I have an `h2` heading and an `h4` sub-heading. I require that the `h4` sub-heading and all its content are indented.

Is there some way I can achieve this? Maybe some sort of a container in markdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of experiments and blog-reading, I finally came up with something. I am answering my own question, as this seems to be quite an issue.

`Markdown` supports `HTML`. So, to indent some content, using the `<ul>` tag was what helped me.

Anything inside `<ul>` will automatically be indented by the browser.

I did face another problem, however. Now, I needed my `HTML` content to include `Markdown` as well. Luckily enough, `Github Flavored Markdown` provides a very simple way to achieve this. Simply leave a `newline` before and after your `HTML` text, and GitHub will have it support `Markdown`.

All in all, my code looked somewhat like this:

```html
<ul>

<li>

I want this `HTML` text to be **bold**.

</ul>
```

which resulted in the output:

I want this `HTML` text to be **bold**.

Comment: Following on from this answer's mention that Markdown supports HTML, I found I'm able to indent text by prepending it with non-breaking spaces.  eg `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text to indent`